# how to give a certain td a class name with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

In a foreach loop in php, a list of rows with its `td` is created. 
In 1 of these rows, the folder has the name `tmp`. Is it possible to give that `td` a class `hidden` so that the folder is not visible?

This is how the foreach produces my html:

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <a href="#">tmp</a>
  </td>
  <td>
     Jan 31 '19
  </td>
  <td>
     1.2 Kb
  </td>
  <td>
     .png
  </td>
  ///
```

So: the `td` in which the anchor with the name `tmp` should get the class name: `hidden` liek below:

```
<tr>
  <td class="hidden">
     <a href="#">tmp</a>
  </td>
  <td>
     Jan 31 '19
  </td>
  <td>
     1.2 Kb
  </td>
  <td>
    .png
  </td>
  ///
```

Comment: Why not just give it the class on the server??? If not then `$("td:has('a')").hide()`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any examples? Did you look up any solutions? Can you edit the PHP code yourself?

Comment: Well, the folder `tmp` is created when an upload file already exists in a certain folder. To give the user a choice for overwriting yes/no i store it temporarily in `tmp` folder. Witch `scandir`, i read all the files and folders in a certain directory. So `tmp` appears also in that list. And because it is not useful for the user, i want to make it "hidden"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just give it the class on the server?

If not then

```js
//$("td:has('a')").addClass("hidden");
// OR 
$("td:has('a:contains(tmp)')").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tr>
  <td>
     <a href="#">tmp</a>
  </td>
  <td>
     Jan 31 '19
  </td>
  <td>
     1.2 Kb
  </td>
  <td>
     .png
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you are not doing it on server side as @mplungjan suggested, but if you want to do it on client side instead of server side;

```js
$(function() {
  $("#folders a:contains('tmp')").parents("td").addClass("hidden");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="folders">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <a href="#">tmp</a>
    </td>
    <td>
       Jan 31 '19
    </td>
    <td>
       1.2 Kb
    </td>
    <td>
      .png
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```